# Benefits of HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css

What are the benefits of using HTML5 and CSS3 a) from development perspective b) from end user perepective ?

I know the standard CSS3 things like border radius, gradient, transforms ,etc

Also any downside of using HTML5 apart from lack of support in older browsers ?

Comment: Do you know what are benefits of HTML and CSS? Multiply it in 5 and 3

Comment: These questions are pretty vague.... please read the faq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here : http://www.html5arena.com/blog/html5/10-major-advantages-of-html5/
there you'll find 10 major advantages of using HTML5

Also the browser support : http://html5test.com/results.html or http://www.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/browser-support-for-css3-and-html5_72/

The disadvantages : http://dvirbab.blogspot.com/2010/03/disadvantages-of-using-html-5.html

Soon, the HTML5 standard will be able to work properly on all browsers.

Comment: Posting only links will not helf future users to find any answers here.

Answer (score 0):

A few benefits that I knew:

**Rich Interface elements not requiring third party plugins.


Seperation of content and design


Enhanced Mobile Support 


New Programming Interfaces**

Some Cons
**HTML5 will not get rid of Flash


HTML5 doesn't use XML Syntax


Too many tags / Tag Soup**

And the future:
**Current mobile browser technology will be the next battle ground.


HTML5 and CSS3 will even the odds with supporting more and more platforms.


The web will no longer be a second class user interface.**